# WordPress responsive theme is displaying Short-codes instead of content

Tags: wordpress, themes, shortcode, responsive

I have a website which is live and is developed using wordPress theme (ThemeForest). The desktop display(including browser size change display) works fine and is responsive but when I view the website from a device, I can see the whole html file including the tags are being displayed as shortCodes. Can anyone please help me identify the reason of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short code displaying means the That short coded function does not existed in that theme please read the short code functionality how works in wordpress. if you have capable to write the function for the theme you can write in its functions.php file.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API refere once.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the header tag displays fine in devices its the contents inside fw-page-builder that are displaying as shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! After two days of research I found out that the mobile theme code of Jet-pack was messed up and throwing out html tags as short-code. I disabled the 'mobile theme' option and everything was working perfectly once again!!

Thank you Srinivas!!! :) :)